# In production rails app, getting Bundler::GemNotFound error, even though instructing bundler to skip development group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

On my production server, I don't want to include the gem rspec rails.  However, when attempting to start my server with rails s, I get an error:

```
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find rspec-rails-2.12.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
    from /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
    from /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:114:in `specs'
    from /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:159:in `specs_for'
    from /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
    from /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler.rb:127:in `setup'
    from /var/www/myapp/releases/20130311164742/config/boot.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from script/rails:5:in `<main>'
```

My gemfile looks like:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
ruby "1.9.3"

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
end

gem 'haml', '3.1.7'
gem 'devise', '2.2.0'
gem 'koala', '1.6.0'
gem "mongoid", "~> 3.0.0"
gem "braintree", "~>2.22.0"


group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.12.0'
end
```

In my config/boot.rb file, I tell bundler only to look for gems included by default or for the relevant environment:

```
require 'rubygems'

# Set up gems listed in the Gemfile.
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)

if File.exists?(ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'])
  require 'bundler'
  Bundler.setup(:default, ENV["RAILS_ENV"])
end
```

I've verified that RAILS_ENV environment variable is set to production, by running:

```
$ echo $RAILS_ENV
```

and getting 'production' back.

Why is it still looking for that gem even though I tell it to not set that up?

Comment: Does the command line output from `rails s` say development or production?

Comment: It didn't say anything.  To your question, to boot.rb I added:
puts ENV["RAILS_ENV"]

and it prints production

Answer (score 0):

Is that a typo? `echo $RAILS_ENV`. You're missing the 's' in Rails.

Comment: yes that was - but just for my test.  doesnt address the actual issue

Comment: are you sure? If you set $RAIL_ENV instead of $RAILS_ENV, the server will be running on the default environment, which is development

Comment: The only typo was in echo $RAIL_ENV - which was just a type when I put in stackoverflow.  echoing that variable only prints it out - how would affect the app?

Comment: do you get the proper behavior when you do `RAILS_ENV=production rails s` instead of relying on the system env variable?

Comment: I've tried that - and even verified without trying that, that the environment variable is set correctly by printing out the value from within the boot.rb file.  Trust me this is not the issue.

Comment: OK, I trust you. Another thought; have your tried `bundle exec rails s` vs `rails s`?